# Find string in file where data is over multiple lines

Tags: linux, find

I would like to return a filename containing certain strings. When viewing the source of the file it is formatted as

```
<Code>5107</Code>
    <Active>False</Active>
```

How can I search for the above data in Linux? I will always be searching XML file

I have tried the following (based upon searches on Stack Overflow) but none are working:

```
find . -iname '*xml' | xargs grep '<Code>5107</Code>
    <Active>False</Active>' -sl

find . -iname '*xml' | xargs grep '<Code>5107</Code>^p<Active>False</Active>' -sl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `gawk`, like

```
gawk '/<Code>5107<\/Code>/ { getline ; if ( $0 ~ "<Active>False</Active>" ) { fnames[FILENAME]++ }
      END { for ( f in fnames ) { print f } }' *XML
```

1. while processing it's arguments if a line matches your `<Code>5107<\/Code>` pattern, slurp the next line and if it matches `<Active>False</Active>` store the `FILENAME` in an array
2. finally print every `FILENAME` with match(es) (only once)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this simple command:
 1.Find command used to find the all xml files 
 2.grep -l - print the file name of matched pattern
 3.grep "patter1\|pattern2" - searched for multiple pattern


[linux-$]find . -iname "*.xml" -exec grep -l "<Code>5107</Code>\|<Active>False</Active>" {} \;
```

Comment: From my understanding he is searching for a multi-line pattern not any of those patterns.